# Acess 2007 adp project with SQL Server 2005 Express database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, adp

I have a strange problem with an Access adp project.  There is a main form with a header and a details sections on a page.  The detaisl section is made up of a tab control that has 7 tabs to it.  Only the 1st tab shows up if I connect the project to a REMOTE SQL Server 2005 Express database.

The same details section with tab control shows up all 7 tabs if I connect the project to a LOCAL SQL server 2005 Express database.  So the only difference is the Remote vs. Local database.  Why would this be an issue.  Everything else in the project works fine except the tab control not showing all 7 tabs when it's connected to the Remote Server.  Any ideas would be appreciated as it's taken me over 6 hrs. to figure this out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well there isn't a lot of information to go on but I would say to make sure your schema and data are identical on the remote and local.  From there you are just going to have to debug the main form.

Comment: I agree, not too much info to go on.  The schemas are identical as I have a backup file that I restored on both databases (local and remote)

Comment: Could it be something that deals with the remote connection?  I enabled remote access on the remote SQL Server, added the firewall rules for SQL Browser and SQL Server, made sure the TCP connection is enabled, enabled the browser service and started it, etc.  Not sure if this is the right track or not.

Comment: If all the connection information (TCP permissions, etc) are set up I would have to say going through the form in debug mode and seeing which queries don't execute properly is your best home.